# 12.04 to 13.10 Can it remove encryption?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, encryption, directory, home-directory

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my primary computer, and I absentmindedly selected "encypt home directory" I read a few methods to de-encrypt it, but they didn't work so well (And seemed overly complicated) If I upgrade from 12.04 to 13.10 will it remove the home directory encryption if I do not select it?
Thanks in advance!!

```
 ~Nate
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, removing the partition on which the `/home` folder resides will remove the encryption. If you have a different `/home` partition, you will need to delete it while installing the new OS, otherwise, if its on the same partition as `/`, then it will be formatted while you install the new OS.

Comment: But do note that you will lose all your data on your home partition by following this method